# Generate Report for Attendace System Group by userid, status

Tags: sql, database

I have the following table for Employee Attendance System

```
userid  CheckTime               CheckType
1       2015-07-31 14:29:18.000     I   
1       2015-07-31 18:29:18.000     O   
1       2015-08-01 08:12:45.000     I   
1       2015-08-02 03:19:03.000     O   
1       2015-08-02 08:15:23.000     I   
1       2015-08-02 14:05:52.000     O   
1       2015-08-02 19:48:57.000     I   
1       2015-08-02 21:48:57.000     O
```

How can get the result as follow

```
userid    checkinTime             CheckOuttime

1         2015-07-31 14:29:18.000 2015-07-31 18:29:18.000
.
.
1         2015-08-01 08:12:45.000 2015-08-02 03:19:03.000
```

Comment: What database are you using? Are the checkin/checkout always pairwise?

Comment: will there be only 1 checkin and only 1 checkout for a given date/userid? Will there be cases where there is a checkin but no checkout, or viceversa?

Comment: SQl server 2008. multiple check in and out for a given user in same date. and maybe checkin with no checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for something like this:

```
Select UserId, Min(CheckTime) As CheckInTime, Max(CheckTime) As CheckOutTime
From EmployeeAttendance
Group By UserId, Cast(CheckTime As Date);
```

**Update 2015-11-02**

For the special case you mentioned, below is a more robust query...

```
Select UserId, InTime.CheckTime As CheckInTime, Min(OutTime.CheckTime) As CheckOutTime
From 
    (Select UserId, CheckTime From EmployeeAttendance Where CheckType = 'I') As InTime
    Left Join 
    (Select UserId, CheckTime From EmployeeAttendance Where CheckType = 'O') As OutTime
    On InTime.UserId = OutTime.UserId
    And InTime.CheckTime < OutTime.CheckTime
Group By UserId, InTime.CheckTime;
```

This query will pick the first checkout time that occurs after each checkin time.

You could take this query a step further by presenting a `CheckOutTime` of `null` when there are two consecutive check ins. It really depends on how you will use this data and how much you trust the data.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but i have a special case when the user check in at 15/1/2015 23:00:00 and checkout 16/1/2015 06:00:00. thank you.

Comment: Thank you Very much for this help, i will test the results and back to you.

Comment: Dear @Mike, is it possible to show id, checkin, checkout group by date as follow.............1/1/2015.............1/2/2015.........1/3/2015.......1/4/2015               .id                  xxxxxx                 xxxxxxxx          xxxxxxx        xxxxxxx                  checkintime   xxxxxx                xxxxxxxx           xxxxxxx       xxxxxxxx                        checkoutime  xxxxxx               xxxxxxxx           xxxxxxx        xxxxxxxx           .......thank u so much.

Comment: Do you want to perform a pivot? If so, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15931734/772086).

Comment: Hello #Mike, in the query above that you sent to me, any updates to cover also when the user did not check in but check out only (i know its a user logic). thank you so much for your help.